# Removing Fluster2 Clusters

Tags: google-maps-markers

I'm using GMap API v3 and Fluster2 to create a map with clustered markers on it.  Everything is fine with adding markers and have them show up as clusters depending on the zoom level.

However, I am having a problem when it's time to clear all the markers so that I can add new ones (based on user input).

```
while(overlays[0]){
   overlays.pop().setMap(null);
}
```

I am using the following code to clear the markers, unfortunately, it only affects the markers (overlays) that are not found within a cluster at the selected zoom level.

Does anyone know how I can remove all markers from the map, meaning all current markers (overlays) showing at the current zoom level AND all other markers found within clusters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to simply create a new map and get rid of the old one.